# Missing Argument 3-How do I fix this error?

Tags: php, symfony

So I'm getting this error message saying that I'm missing an argument for a school project that I'm working on, and the code is being called here:

```
isconcurrent = $this->get('session')->get('is_concurrent');
$session->set('id_phase', '');
```

And it's defined here:

```
public function hasrights($user, $site_slug, $isconcurrent)
{
$site = $this->dem->getRepository('DocumentInfo')->findOneByDocumentId($book_slug->getId());

    if($site->Access()){
        $this->session->set('is_access',1);
    }else{
        $this->session->set('is_access',0);
    }
    if($isconcurrent && $this->session->get('concurrent_information')->id_list){
        if (in_array($site_slug->getId(), $this->session->get('cocurrent_information')->id_list)){
           return true; 
        }else{
           return false;
        }
    }else if ($user) {
        if ($site_slug && 1 == $site->Access()) {
            $allow_access = $this->authentication($user->getEmail(), $book->getSku());
            return $allow_access;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Why is there an error here? Isconcurrent is argument 3, and it's being called in the code, so why is there an error message that pops up?

Comment: maybe you are missing the `$` in front of isconcurrent

Comment: you were right can't believe I missed that! thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the code you pasted here you are missing the `$` in front of your variable declaration

$isconcurrent = $this->get('session')->get('is_concurrent');

Comment: You were right can't believe I missed that and didn't see it thank you so much!